# Replacing FSA Mega Exo with Shimano RS500 crankset

Tags: shimano, compact-crankset

Just bought a Jamis Renegade Explore which is the Sora equipped gravel bike.  Only thing i can't stand is the fsa mega exo crank and square taper bottom bracket.  I happen to have s brand new hollowtech 2 shimano rs500 crankset lying around and would only need to grab an external bb for like 20 bucks.  Question is...will the rs500 crankset work with the 9 speed sora3000 groupset ??

Answer (score 1):

Road cranks have spindles long enough for 68mm BB shells plus external Hollowtech bearings. The Jamis has a 68mm bottom bracket shell, so the RS500 crank will fit the frame.

Make sure you get a 'road' BB for 68mm shells *not* an 'MTB' BB for 73mm shells, or 68mm shells with spacers. Those are too wide for the crank spindle.

Presumably the RS500 crank has the same chainring sizes and crank arm length as the FSA, so there are no problems there.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was worried that because it's a 9 speed groupset, it can't accept an 11 speed crank.  Thought I read that somewhere but I probably read wrong.  This is great news!

Comment: @Danbob Well, my answer is really about the crank fitting the frame. There is a concern about a 9 speed chain working on a nominally 11 speed crank. which I kinda forgot about. I'm tempted to think it will work OK. I remember there are questions about mismatched speed cranks on this site that you can check out.